# is it correct to say "at the lessons"?

Tags: adverbial-phrases, adverbials

Many Russian textbooks use the adverbial "at the lessons" meaning that something takes place during some lessons/classes.

For example: "Children call each other names at the lessons".

I heard that native speakers never used this adverbial and it's a mistake in Russian textbooks.

Do natives usually use "in class" or "in the lessons" when they mean that something takes place during classes? Please, make it clear.

Comment: Yes, as a native speaker I say "in class" or "in the lesson", or "during the lesson".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At the lessons" is not idiomatic, but it's also unclear what your sentence is trying to say.  This sounds like a direct translation of a Russian idiom, that might not have the intended meaning in English.  I can think of three possible meanings:

1. If you mean *during the general time spent in an institution of learning* (both inside and outside the classroom), then "at school" is probably the most idiomatic choice:

   > Children often call each other names **at school**.
2. If you mean *during the time spent in the classroom*, then "in class" is idiomatic:

   > Children often call each other names **in class**.
3. If you specifically mean *during the time spent learning school subjects*, then "during lessons" is idiomatic:

   > Children often call each other names **during lessons**.

Without knowing more context, it's impossible to say which works best.  Personally, I would be more likely to say "in school" because I recognize that children are more likely to call each other names where teachers and other authority figures won't overhear them.  But this may be different in other school systems.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually more natural and idiomatic to say "in lessons" rather than "in *the* lessons". In your specific example, the word *during* sounds better still:

> Children call each other names *during* lessons.

That said, in a context where you have already specified certain lessons, it could be appropriate to use the definite article to refer back to them. For example:

> We will be doing a special project for 6 weeks. *During the lessons*, children will partake in different activities.

This seems correct because you have referred to *specific* lessons (only those during the 6-week project).